# unable to understand comma separated variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

if

`a, b = 0, 1`

means

```
a = 0 
b = 1
```

then

`a, b = b , a + b`

should be

```
a = b 
b = a + b
```

but if I use that in fib function at (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) it does not work. can some one help me understand how it work ?

so output of

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print(a, end = ' ')
        a = b 
        b = a + b 
    print()

fib(50)
```

is `0 1 2 4 8 16 32`

Comment: I think it is important to point out  a logic error. `a = b` is the problem. So the next line `b = a + b` is actually `b + b`.